# Show the final y-axis value of each line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing a graph with some lines using matplotlib and I want to display the final `y` value next to where each line ends on the right hand side like this:
[image]

Any solutions or pointers to the relevant parts of the API? I'm quite stumped.

I'm using matplotlib 1.0.0 and the pyplot interface, e.g. `pyplot.plot(xs, ys, f, xs_, ys_, f_)`.

Comment: Thanks for the image-embedding edit!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with Ofri's answer, `annotate` is intended especially for this purpose:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(61).astype(np.float)
y1 = np.exp(0.1 * x)
y2 = np.exp(0.09 * x)

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)

for var in (y1, y2):
    plt.annotate('%0.2f' % var.max(), xy=(1, var.max()), xytext=(8, 0), 
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

This places the text 8 *points* to the right of the right side of the axis, at the maximum y-value for each plot. You can also add in arrows, etc. See http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/annotations_guide.html   (You can also change the vertical alignment, if you want the text vertically centered on the given y-value. Just specify `va='center'`.)

Also, this doesn't rely on tick locations, so it will work perfectly for log plots, etc.  Giving the location of the text in terms of the positions of the axis boundaries and its offset in points has a lot of advantages if you start rescaling the plot, etc.

Comment: While working for this particular example, this solution assumes that the values are increasing and the final value is equal to the max value. If you really want the final value use: 

`
    plt.annotate('%0.2f' % var[-1], xy=(1, var.max()), xytext=(8, 0), 
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
`

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1** - [pyplot.text](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)

```
pyplot.text(x, y, string, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs)
```

**Option 2** - Use a [second axes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.twinx):

```
second_axes = pyplot.twinx() # create the second axes, sharing x-axis
second_axis.set_yticks([0.2,0.4]) # list of your y values
pyplot.show() # update the figure
```

Comment: The first option does the job (mostly, see my comment above) but I really like the second one! Have to set up the same axis formatter by hand, but that's no problem. Thanks!

Comment: However, it has some difficulty when the y axis is log scale. The numbers are drawn as though the new axis isn't. If the second y axis is set to log scale too then the numbers aren't drawn.

Answer (score 4):

Very useful Joe.  Only one more detail. If the final value isn't a maximun, you can use y[-1].  I added a horizontal line to clarify.

```
gbm = np.log(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10000))+10000)
plt.plot(gbm)
plt.annotate('%0.2f' % gbm[-1], xy=(1, gbm[-1]), xytext=(8, 0), 
             xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
plt.axhline(y=gbm[-1], color='y', linestyle='-.')
plt.show()
```

[Plot with final y-axis value marked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiajR.png)

Comment: How to assign value by groups in data frame?